# fundamental group and admitting a z_2-map to circle

Tags: algebraic-topology

There is a lemma (Lemma 6.1) in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.05290.pdf without proof. I would be so grateful if someone could help me regrading the proof.

For completeness, I rewrite the lemma here:

**Notation**: In following, the orbit space of a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-space $X$ is denoted by  $\overline{X}$.

**Lemma**: Let $X$ be a free connected Z_2-simplicial complex. Then there is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map from X to $\mathbb{S}^1$ if and only if there is a group homomorphisim $f: \pi_1(\overline{X})\to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^{-1}(2\mathbb{Z})=\pi_1(X).$

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all relies on the $2$-fold covering map $p: S^1\to S^1, z\mapsto z^2$.

Indeed suppose there is a $\mathbb Z/2$-map $g:X\to S^1$, then $X\to S^1\overset{p}\to S^1$ is $\mathbb Z/2$-equivariant , so factors through $\overline X$, and we get $\overline X\to S^1$ such that the following diagram commutes :

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} X @>g>> S^1 \\
@VqVV @VpVV \\
\overline X @>f>> S^1\end{CD}$$

and then $f_* : \pi_1(\overline X)\to \pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb Z$ satisfies the condition (indeed, clearly $f_*q_*\pi_1(X) \subset 2\mathbb Z$; and conversely suppose $f_*\gamma \in 2\mathbb Z$, and let $\gamma : I\to \overline X$ be the corresponding map.

Then $\gamma : I\to \overline X$ may be lifted to a *path* (which is not a priori a loop) $\delta : I\to X$. But now $q(\delta(0))= q(\delta(1))$, so either $\delta(0) = \delta(1)$, in which case  we have nothing to say ($\delta$ is a loop, and $q_*\delta = \gamma$), or $\delta(0) = \sigma \delta(1)$ (where $\sigma \in\mathbb Z/2$ is the generator); in which case $g\delta(0) = \sigma g\delta(1)$, and so they are different.

But they're the endpoints of $g\delta$ which is a lift $I\to S^1$ of $f\circ \gamma : I\to S^1$, and such a lift is necessarily a loop, because $f_*\gamma \in 2\mathbb Z = p_*\pi_1(S^1)$.

This is absurd, so $\delta(0) = \delta(1)$ and therefore $\gamma \in q_*\pi_1(X)$.

Conversely, suppose you have such a map $f: \pi_1(\overline X)\to \mathbb Z$. Then since $S^1$ is a $K(\mathbb Z,1)$, that is, it has no higher homotopy, this map can be used to produce a map $\tilde f : \overline X\to S^1$ which is such that $\tilde f_* = f$.

Then we can compose it to get $X\to \overline X\to S^1$, and the image of $\pi_1(X)$ is $\subset 2\mathbb Z$ by assumption. It follows by general covering theory that this yields a lift, and so a commutative diagram :

$$\begin{CD} X @>g>> S^1 \\
@VqVV @VpVV \\
\overline X @>\tilde f>> S^1\end{CD}$$

Now we just need to show that the top map is a $\mathbb Z/2$-map (note that we still haven't used that $f^{-1}(2\mathbb Z) = \pi_1(X)$, we only used one inclusion, so we'll need to use the second inclusion).

Let $x\in X$ and let $y = \sigma x$. Then $p(g(y)) = \tilde f(q(y)) = \tilde f(q(x)) = p(g(x))$, so $g(y)= g(x)$ or $\sigma g(x)$. We just need to show that the former is not possible.

Let $\delta$ be a path in $X$ from $x$ to $y$ ($X$ is connected), and consider $q\circ \delta$ : it's a loop in $\overline X$, let's call it $\gamma$. Then $f(\gamma)\in \pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb Z$ is *not* in $2\mathbb Z$. Indeed if it were, then $\gamma$ would be in $q_*\pi_1(X)$, which it isn't, as $x\neq y$ (the action on $X$ is free, by assumption).

Therefore $f(\gamma)$ does *not* lift to a loop along $p : S^1\to S^1$, and in particular, since $g\circ \delta$ is a *path* that lifts $f\circ \gamma$, it follows that $g\circ \delta$ cannot be a loop, i.e. $g(\delta(0))\neq g(\delta(1))$, i.e. $g(x) \neq g(y)$.

By what we said earlier, it follows that $g(y) = \sigma g(x)$, i.e. $g$ is a $\mathbb Z/2$-map, and we are done.

Comment: Ramzi: Thank you very much for your time and excellent explanation. I have just missed one part of your proof (sorry I am very beginner in this staff). Could you please explain the part about construction the $\tilde f$, i.e, "Then since $S^1$ is a $K(\mathbb Z,1)$, that is, it has no higher homotopy, this map can be used to produce a map $\tilde f : \overline X\to S^1$ which is such that $\tilde f_* = f$."

Comment: Right, the answer will depend on how much topology you know. Do you know that $S^1$ has no higher homotopy groups ? Do you also know that $\overline X$ can be given the structure of a simplicial complex, or CW-complex, or some type of complex built out of nice cells ? Using these things, one can show that the map that assigns to a homotopy class of functions $f: \overline X\to S^1$ its induced morphism $f_* : \pi_1(\overline X)\to \pi_1(S^1)$ is a bijection

Comment: To see the surjection part (which is all you really need), you can construct the topological map by working your way up the skeleton of $\overline X$, attaching new cells at a time, and noticing that you can do that precisely because $S^1$ has no higher homotopy groups (and for adding $1$-cells, you can do that because you're starting from a map $\pi_1(\overline X)\to \pi_1(S^1)$

Comment: Thanks a million for your time and the comments. Well, from the first place I should mentioned with which part I have problem. Yes, I know about those questions you asked. So, let me explain a bit more about the part that I have not understood yet. I know if map is defined on the second skeleton then it can be extend to whole the space as the higher homotopy  groups of the circle is zero. So, my problem is that how do you exactly construct the map up to 2-skeleton with the desired property?

Comment: Right that is not obvious. I don't know the easiest way to do it. One possible way is to replace $\overline X$ with an equivalent CW-complex that's built "for" this. So you take a set $S$ that generates $\pi_1(\overline X)$ (it could be the whole thing, but to build smaller things it can be useful), and you create a CW-complex equivalent to $\overline X$ which has exactly one $1$-cell for each element of $S$, then $2$-cells for the relations between those, then you add $3$-cells to kill unwanted members of  $\pi_2$ and to add wanted members of $\pi_3$ etc

Comment: This lets you build inductively a CW-complex $\tilde X$ with an inductively defined weak equivalence $h: \tilde X\to \overline X$ - it's also a homotopy equivalence by Whitehead, so we may as well replace $\overline X$ by $\tilde X$. But now $\tilde X$ has a nice form : you can easily define $\tilde f : \tilde X\to S^1$ on the $2$-skeleton (where does each $1$-cell go ? well a $1$-cell is a person $s\in S$, so it has a prescribed loop in $S^1$ to which it's sent !); and then, as you said, going higher up is easy

Comment: (this is probably not the easiest way to do that, but that's definitely one possible way, and it's a good technique to have under your belt)

Comment: Woops I forgot, of course you're also supposed to add $2$-cells if you need some ! Hopefully you would have filled that

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and the clarifications.